# Android Front-Facing Camera Preview Size

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app that I am working on that makes use of the front-facing camera on the device. I am trying to set the preview size by getting the list of supported preview sizes and looping through them looking for one that is pretty close. The method that I wrote to do so is basically the same as the one from the OS's own camera app. The method works fine, exactly how I would like it to, that's not why I am here.

I was having problems with the camera preview looking obviously skewed on some devices; either squishing or stretching the preview of the image. I couldn't figure out why it was doing this so I stepped through it and looked at all of the supported preview sizes available to my front-facing camera and found that there were only 2 and neither of them were the correct aspect to be usable. My "surfaceChanged" method in my SurfaceHolder.Callback class is reporting a width and height of 762x480 for the front-facing camera, but of the two supported preview sizes (acquired with cam.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()) both were in the opposite aspect: 480x800, 320x640.

With these as the only options, it seems impossible to have a preview for my front-facing camera that is not skewed. I know that in versions 2.3 or less, arbitrary values can be used for width and height without regard to supported sizes, but I am trying to make my app work for newer versions of the OS as well. How can I make the preview look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial question remains technically unsolved (and I still believe it to be impossible) however I did figure out the trick to a non-skewed preview.

Given the supported preview sizes all being in the incorrect orientation compared to my device's screen it does indeed seem impossible to have a normal preview *that fills the entire screen.* After looking at several native camera apps on different devices (all of which that display the front-facing preview with no skewing at all) I noticed that very few of the devices (only one, in fact, and that one had a non-standard screen size) had previews that covered the entire screen as I was attempting to do in my app.

I reworked my app to get the size with the closest width and height to the device screen, but without going over in either dimension or in aspect ratio, and then manually set the height and width of the SurfaceView to match the selected size. True there is a small amount of black space around the preview on some devices now, but it definitely looks much better than being skewed. I had a panel with buttons for snapping a picture and manipulating flash settings, etc. on one side anyways, so it really is less noticeable than one might think.